# C pre-processor how to treat function macro as string

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am using mingw to compile C++ code on OSX for Windows.  The C++ code is auto generated and includes MS Visual Studio-specific code:

```
class __declspec(novtable) SomeClass
```

When I compile, I get lots of warnings:

```
warning: ‘novtable’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
```

I want to suppress these warnings.  Mingw does not support the `-Wno-microsoft` option, so I thought I might be able to get `__declspec(notable)` to be treated as an identifier pointing to an empty string and have the pre-processor remove it.

i.e.

```
#define __declspec(novtable)
```

However, this is treated as a re-definition of the `__declspec()` macro, which is not the desired behaviour.

Is there a way to get the pre-processor to treat `__declspec(novtable)` as an identifier, or otherwise suppress this warning?  (The offending auto-generated code cannot be modified).

Comment: Did you want to preserve other `__declspec` and just ignore novtable?

Comment: Why can't you modify the generated code? Running `sed` (or `awk`) over the code would be reasonably convenient.

Comment: I'd love to modify the code, but it's auto generated and needs to remain untouched so that it can be built on multiple platforms.  Others may wish to build with the VC code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the compiler has this definition in effect

```
#define __declspec(x) __attribute__((x))
```

and also recognizes some (not all) Microsoft-specific attributes like `dllexport` and `dllimport`. The following only makes sense if the above hypothesis is true.

You can use

```
 #undef __declspec // to suppress a meessage about macro redefinition
 #define __declspec(x) // nothing
```

(perhaps suitably `#ifdef`ed so as not to break compatibility with MSVC).

This will kill the whole `__declspec` feature, not just `__declspec(novtable)`. If this is not what you need, read on.

If you only need to kill `__declspec(novtable)` and leave all the other attributes intact, try this

```
#define novtable // nothing
```

The `__attribute__` directive may contain a possibly empty list of attributes, so `__declspec(novtable)` will presumably translate to `__attribute__(())`, which is perfectly OK. This will also kill all other occurrences of the identifier `novtable`. If it does occur in any other context, which is not too likely but possible, this option won't work fro you.

Another possibility is to take over the entire feature.

```
#undef __declspec
#define __declspec(x) my_attribute_ # x

#define my_attribute_dllexport __attribute__((dllexport)) // or whatever you need
#define my_attribute_dllimport __attribute__((dllimport)) // or whatever you need
// ... same for all attributes you do need

#define my_attribute_novtable // nothing
// ... same for all attributes you don't need
```

Comment: This is _such_ a blunt instrument...!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit huh?

Comment: You killed the entire `__declspec` feature for the entire subsequent code, assuming it was a macro in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's the point. There is no such feature in C++.

Comment: Hmmm. I suppose. OP was asking specifically about `__declspec(novtable)` but, now you mention it...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I've updated the answer, just in case if OP needs other declspec attributes,

Comment: Much better answer now :)

Answer (score 2):

Define your `__declspec(novtable)` with some macro:

```
 #define DECL_SPEC __declspec(novtable)
```

After that you can use it as:

```
 class DECL_SPEC SomeClass
```

And redefine `DECL_SPEC` as empty when required:

```
 #ifdef __MINGW32__
 #define DECL_SPEC
 #else
 #define DECL_SPEC __declspec(novtable)
 #endif
```

Comment: Isn't that backwards? He doesn't want to use `class DECL_SPEC`, he wants to ignore `__declspec(novtable)` in generated code without warning. (And it feels like you're confusing the order of `#define` arguments with `typedef` argument order.)

Comment: @Rup No, it's not backwards at all. What this answer means is: "Don't generate `__declspec(novtable)` into your code, generate `DECL_SPEC` instead. Then, you can `#define DECL_SPEC` to something or nothing as necessary.

Comment: Not sure how to just ignore the warning, @John can try `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wattributes"`

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, particularly now you've fixed the `#define` line. But that's still modifying the generated code, if in a slightly more-palatable way, and `NO_VTABLE` would be a much better name for the macro.